# Вынести репозиторий из рабочего каталога

Tags: git

День добрый.

Есть сайт, который лежит в каталоге /var/www/site/ .
 В вышеуказанном каталоге находится репозиторий, доступный по адресу /var/www/site/.git .

Как можно вынести репозиторий из рабочего каталога, т.е. чтобы .git располагался не в `/var/www/site/.git`, а в `/git/site/.git`.

Спасибо!

Comment: Зачем? Не проще настроить nginx, чтобы отдавал статику из поддиректории public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько понимаю, достаточно просто использовать опции --git-dir и --work-tree, указывающие, соответственно, на репозиторий и на рабочую копию.

Comment: @Etki да, это верно, если точнее, то 

    git config core.worktree <путь к рабочему каталогу.>

Answer (score 0):

ещё один возможный вариант:

переместить *docroot* хотя бы на один уровень глубже.

---

пример: перемещаем все файлы/каталоги внутрь каталога (например) `docroot`.

1. создаём новый каталог (добавив точку в начало его названия, чтобы не получить ошибки на следующем шаге):

   ```
   $ mkdir .docroot
   ```
2. перемещаем в этот каталог всё содержимое текущего каталога:

   ```
   $ git mv * .docroot
   ```
3. переименовываем каталог, убирая первый символ — точку — из его имени:

   ```
   $ git mv .docroot docroot
   ```
4. проверяем, всё ли верно:

   ```
   $ git status
   # On branch master
   # Changes to be committed:
   #   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
   #
   #   renamed:    dir/index.html -> docroot/dir/index.html
   #   renamed:    index.html -> docroot/index.html
   #
   ```
5. делаем `git commit`

теперь *docroot* сайта будет находиться в `/var/www/site/docroot`, а репозиторий будет располагаться уровнем выше (в `/var/www/site/.git`) и, соответственно, станет недоступен *http-серверу* (без дополнительной его конфигурации).