# Как переместить .git-папку выше на уровень?

Tags: git, репозиторий, git-pull

На рабочем сервере в корневой папке сайта public_html помимо файлов и папок сайта есть собственно пака .git. Обновление файлов сайта происходит из Git-репозитория.
Как можно переместить папку .git выше директории public_html при этом не сломав ничего (чтобы команда git pull так же как и раньше обновляла содержимое папки public_html )

Comment: Еще, как вариант, можно настроить ваш HTTP сервер, чтобы он не отдавал содержимое папки .git.

Comment: применение .htaccess с "deny from all" внутри?

Comment: Зависит от вашего сервера. Но я бы не советовал класть что-то в .git.

Comment: В статье http://habrahabr.ru/post/70330/ есть решение.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку на интересную статью! Перемещение  репозитория (папки .git) за пределы корневой папки сайта конечно было бы идеальным решением, вот только ничего толком не понятно как это делать...

Comment: ещё возможная практика — это размещать *docroot* не в корне рабочей копии, а в каталоге глубже хотя бы на один уровень.

Answer (score 1):

Флаг --git-dir=путь_до_.git вам поможет, либо переменная окружения GIT_DIR, а вообще это [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/371517/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0)